# Merge a custom figure in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have custom that creates of map of the US in powerpoint.

```
Sub ArrayLoop(array1, array2, amountOfLine)


 Dim i As Long
 For i = 0 To amountOfLine
 With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=array1(i), BeginY:=array2(i), EndX:=array1(i + 1), EndY:=array2(i + 1)).Line
  .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
 End With
Next
End Sub


Sub TestArrayLoop()

 Dim USA1, USA2
 Dim amount As Integer

 USA1 = Array(316.0954, 321.021, 332.9831, 337.205, 337.205, 346.4698, 
351.3953, 354.9135, 361.9501, 367.5793, 370.394, 371.8012, 374.6158, 376.7268, 
375.3195, 376.7268, 383.0596, 385.1706, 378.8377, 376.0232, 378.1341, 
378.8377, 368.9866, 364.061, 366.172, 371.0976, 373.9122, 382.356, 388.6888, 
393.6144, 397.1327, 394.318, 393.6144, _
384.4669, 384.4669, 376.7268, 374.6158, 369.6902, 368.2829, 366.172, 
366.172, 
361.9501, 358.4318, 354.9135, 350.6917, 347.8771, 347.8771, 347.8771, 
347.1734, 346.4698, 350.6917, 343.6551, 345.0624, 342.2478, 339.4332, 
337.9087, 
330.8721, 317.5027, 314.6881, 312.5772, 310.4662, 316.0954, 319.6137, 
323.132, 325.2429, 327.3539, 328.7612, 335.7977, 339.4332, 337.205, 
338.7296, 
335.7977, 331.5757, 330.1685, 325.9465, 324.5393, 322.4283, 319.6137, 
318.2064, 315.3918, 313.9845, 309.7626, 306.2443, 306.2443, 311.1698, 
311.8735, 
308.3553, 306.2443, 303.4297, 302.0224, 297.0969, 290.0603, 285.8384, 279.5055, 280.2092, 280.9128, 278.8019, 275.2836, 267.5435, 264.0252, 265.4325, 
260.5069, 254.8777, 247.1376, 242.212, 237.2865, 223.917, 220.3988, 214.7696, 211.2513, 206.9121, 206.9121, 214.0659, 219.6951, 227.4353, 232.3609, 
231.6572, 233.7682, 239.3974, 247.1376, 247.8412, 309.0589, 316.0954)

 USA2 = Array(247.1064, 248.5467, 254.3079, 263.6699, 267.9909, 265.1102, 260.7893, 260.0691, 258.6288, 251.4273, 252.1475, 259.349, 257.1885, 257.9087, 
 260.0691, 262.9498, 257.9087, 255.028, 254.3079, 249.987, 247.8265, 244.9459, 247.1064, 251.4273, 246.3862, 243.5056, 240.625, 241.3451, 240.625, 
 237.0242, 234.1435, 226.942, 223.3412, 218.3002, 215.4195, 200.2962, 206.7776, 208.218, 206.7776, 206.7776, 196.5754, 195.8553, 190.8142, 191.5343, 
 190.094, 190.8142, 194.415, 198.1357, 206.0575, 208.9381, 217.58, 224.0613, 234.8637, 237.0242, 235.5839, 222.621, 221.9009, 213.9792, 213.9792, 207.4978, 
 205.3373, 187.9335, 184.3327, 182.1723, 182.1723, 174.9708, 169.2095, 
 167.7692, _
 164.8886, 158.4072, 154.0862, 150.4854, 149.7653, 156.9669, 163.4483, 155.5265, 152.6459, 156.2467, 152.6459, 147.6049, 141.1235, 133.9219, 144.0041, 
147.6049, 151.9258, 156.2467, 159.8475, 158.4072, 158.4072, 162.0079, 160.5676, 160.5676, 157.687, 159.1273, 161.2878, 165.6087, 164.8886, 160.5676, 
162.0079, 159.1273, 156.2467, 154.8064, 151.9258, 149.7653, 151.2056, 145.4444, 151.9258, 155.5265, 154.0862, 150.4854, 149.0452, 200.2962, 203.897, 
201.0164, 215.4195, 219.0203, 224.7815, 229.1024, 237.0242, 242.0653, 245.6661, 245.6661, 247.1064)


 amount = UBound(USA1) - LBound(USA2) + 1
 amount = amount - 2
 ArrayLoop USA1, USA2, amount  
 End Sub
```

This all works fine but the thing is that now I cant select the whole figure. So im looking for a way so I merge in it a figure which I can drag around the screen.

Any thoughts on how I can do this? Preferably in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you are adding many individual lines.  For the code to work the way you envision, you somehow have to add your shape as a single line.  To do this, change your sub from this:

```
Sub ArrayLoop(array1, array2, amountOfLine)
   Dim i As Long

   For i = 0 To amountOfLine
      With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddLine(BeginX:=array1(i), BeginY:=array2(i), EndX:=array1(i + 1), EndY:=array2(i + 1)).Line
         .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
         .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
      End With
   Next
End Sub
```

to this:

```
Sub ArrayLoop(array1, array2)
   'you will need a single array of points for the call.
   'whether you want to pass in 2 arrays and then merge them
   'or pass in a single merged array is up to you

   With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPolyline(<an array of points>).Line
      .DashStyle = msoLineDashDotDot
      .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 0, 128)
   End With
End Sub
```

You will need to tweak your array of points to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your input Brian. However, when I change the code I get the following compile error: cant find the argument. Any thoughts?

Comment: The parameters for the call are different.  Instead of X, Y, X, Y you need to pass an array of points.  I will modify my answer to make this more clear.